# WebConfig: use @bean or method way?

Tags: java, spring

I know that i can write in webConfig class in this way:

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
}
```

But at the same time - i can write this in another way:

```
 @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}
```

which way is better ?

And why i can't do first way for freemarker, but can do second:

it is correct:

```
@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    return viewResolver;
}


@Bean(name = "freemarkerConfig")
public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreemarkerConfig() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer config = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    config.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    return config;
}
```

Method way i can't write because i don't know how FreeMarkerConfigurer and FreeMarkerViewResolver interact...

Answer (score 0):

Basically your second usage is not how you should use the `ViewResolverRegistry` it has some methods to make life easier, like `jsp` or `freeMarker` which you should use.

So a proper use would be

```
Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
  registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/pages/", ".jsp");

}
```

and for FreeMarker

```
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
  registry.freeMarker(); 

}

@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer config = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    config.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    return config;
}
```

You still need the `FreeMarkerConfigurer` to bootstrap and configure FreeMarker.

Comment: Thank you very much) Can you explain me - what's the difference between config.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/pages/"); and registry.freeMarker().setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");   ?

Comment: The config one is the base path for loading the templates and is setup directly on FreeMarker itself. The prefix is used as part of the view name which is then passed to FreeMarker, which will load the actual template from the base path + the view name . With a lot of views it is handy to have a base path with several sub directories.